# Div centering CSS

Tags: css, html

I am struggling with my website, I am trying to get the divs at the bottom to go in the center. The main text section centers and displays fine, its only the footer where the text won't align in the center. Has anyone got any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is my css code.

```
#footer{
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-image: url(images/jf_footer.png);
color: #C7C7C7;
font-size: 0.75em;


}

#footercontainer{
width: 960px;
margin:0px auto;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#footertext{
float: left;
text-align:center;
margin-top: 15px;
color: #C7C7C7;
font-size: 1em;
}

#footerlinks{
float: left;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footercontainer">
        <div id="footertext">Copyright NV Blinds 2012</div>
        <div id="footerlinks">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>The Collections</li>
                <li>Distributors</li>
                <li>Our Team</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some HTML code and please provide a _minimal_ example. Most of the css shown will not effect the divs in question I suppose.

Comment: Can you add basic markup, because CSS alone does not really make sense. Also clean the css to keep the relevant part only.

Comment: if you post them in a JSFiddle it would be really helpful

Comment: there is a lot of unecessary css here which make it confusing, also provide usage of footercontainer, footertext and footerlinks

Comment: #footerconatiner a spelling error?

Comment: Because of top margins and width, I ques footer and footertext are nested inside footerconatiner

Comment: Footer Container was a spelling mistake sorry about that, however it still won't center it aligns to the far left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to guess what exactly you are looking for.. i've aligned the links side by site and the `#footerContainer` is at the center -- you can check it if the window size is more than `960px`.. well,enough said -- check the demo

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f63Nv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your HTML but I guess it may be because you use float:left in your footer related styles.

I think the main reason that you don't get text aligned in the center is the fact that using floating on containers (div) will make them have width equal to content, but not 100%.

So text-align (which only has effect on inline elements like links, spans, inputs) can't align the content in the center because it already takes the full size.

I guess the problem is here: using float:left with conjunction of text-align:

```
#footertext{
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Removed the text-align center. unfortunatly still right on the left handside. i basically want the div #footerconatiner{ which is 960px wide to center on the page, at the moment the footertext is going to the furthest left

Comment: <div id="footer">
    <div id="footercontainer">
     <div id="footertext">Copyright NV Blinds 2012</div>
    
     <div id="footerlinks">
   <ul>
             <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>The Collections</li>
                <li>Distributors</li>
                <li>Our Team</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
           </ul>
     </div>
       </div>

    </div>

Comment: @user1061995 remove `float:left` instead not text-align, also try to put `clear:both;`

Comment: appologies its the div i'd like centered, that was a slight mistake with the text-align: center bit so basically ive got the footer which is the full width of the page, and then in the footer, the div footer container which is 960px wide and centered and then the footertext and footerlinks divs side by side

Answer (score 0):

See my CSS below with notes. I've included the bare minimum you need to get what I believe is your desired effect. (If you want both the `#footertext` and `#footerlinks` to be on the same line, just add `display:inline` to both ids.

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
}

#footercontainer{ /* corrected spelling to match HTML id */
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto; /* horizontally centers div */
}

#footertext{
    text-align: center; /* horizontally center text */
}

#footerlinks{
    text-align: center; /* horizontally center text */
}

#footerlinks ul {
    list-style: none; /* remove bullets from list */
}
#footerlinks ul li {
    display: inline; /* make li elements inline */
}
```