# How do I center a link with an image in order to respond to responsive design?

Tags: html, css

I have an element which looks weird in mobile, it is not totally center as I need it,so I want to know if there is any kind of standard in order to center things in any resolution.

Look:

```
<li> 
   <div class="asoc-director">                                     
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="client-director">
            <img class="card-picture-admins" src="assets/images/team/my-img.png">
            <span class="name-role" id="37">Sigfried Bermudez <br> Associate Director</span>
        </a>           
    </div>
</li>
```

and the css for is:

```
.asoc-director {
    padding-top: 46px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
}

li > div a:first-child {
    left: 35%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Div centering CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414344/div-centering-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is. It's called flexbox, which is is a property of `display`. Use `display: flex` on the container in conjunction with `align-content: center` and `justify-content: center` to center the children.